# What does ^ character mean in grep ^d?

Tags: unix, command-line, grep

When I do `ls -l | grep ^d` it lists only directories in the current directory.

What I'd like to know is what does the character ^ in ^d mean?

Comment: It matches the beginning of the string.

Comment: Literally it means "starts with", so `^d` is "starts with `d`"

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3077/what-does-d-mean-in-ls-l-grep-d (possible duplicate)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The caret `^` and the dollar sign `$` are meta-characters that respectively match the empty string at the beginning and end of a line.The grep is matching only lines that start with "d".

Comment: thanks for explanation but mentioned link has broken , could you give another one

Comment: @Avenger Thanks for pointing out the broken link, I will find a suitable one and post.

Answer (score 5):

To complement [the good answer by The New Idiot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17059553/1983854), I want to point out that this:

```
ls -l | grep ^d
```

**Shows all directories in the current directory**. That's because the `ls -l` adds a `d` in the beginning of the directories info.

The format of `ls -l` is like:

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 user group    0 Jun 12 12:25 exec_file
-rw-rw-r--  1 user group    0 Jun 12 12:25 normal_file
drwxr-xr-x 16 user group 4096 May 24 12:46 dir
^
|___ see the "d"
```

To make it more clear, you can `ls -lF` to include a `/` to the end of the directories info:

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 user group    0 Jun 12 12:25 exec_file*
-rw-rw-r--  1 user group    0 Jun 12 12:25 normal_file
drwxr-xr-x 16 user group 4096 May 24 12:46 dir/
```

So `ls -lF | grep /$` will do the same as `ls -l | grep ^d`.

Answer (score 1):

It has two meanings. One as 'The New Idiot' above pointed out. The other, equally useful, is within character class expression, where it means negation: `grep -E '[^[:digit:]]' accepts any character except a digit. The`^` must be the first character within [].